# Spark - Reduce with division operator

Tags: scala, apache-spark, division, reduce

I have 2 sets, one with positive and one with negative samples. First value in array is item identification, second value refers to sum of such items.

```
positive: Array[(String, Int)]

negative: Array[(String, Int)]
```

I would like to construct array result, which will contain item name and its positive to negative ratio as float number. The command below returns me only integer ratio.

```
val result = positive.union(negativeCount).reduceByKey((a, b) => (a / b)
```

Can you please advice how to make the ratio a float number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand your intentions you should use `join` not an `union`

```
val positive = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 1), ("b", 2)))
val negative = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 4), ("b", 1)))

val ratios = positive
  .join(negative)
  .mapValues{case (x: Int, y: Int) => x.toFloat / y}

ratios.collect
// Array[(String, Float)] = Array((a,0.25), (b,2.0))
```

With DataFrames:

```
val ratiosDF = positive.toDF("pk", "pv")
  .join(negative.toDF("nk", "nv"), $"pk" === $"nk")
  .select($"pk".alias("k"), $"pv".divide($"nv").alias("v"))
ratiosDF.show

// +---+----+
// |  k|   v|
// +---+----+
// |  a|0.25|
// |  b| 2.0|
// +---+----+
```

Using `union` followed by `reduceByKey` doesn't make sense and gives no strong guarantees about the order of values.

Answer (score -1):

Make one of the integers float using `toFloat`

```
val result = positive.union(negativeCount)
  .mapValues(_.toFloat)
  .reduceByKey((a, b) => (a / b))
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it returns me
    <console>:32: error: type mismatch;
    found   : Float
    required: Int

Comment: Oh yes, because reduce by key requires the same output type as the input type. Do a `map(_.toFloat)` before you run reduceByKey

`val result = positive.union(negativeCount).mapValues(_.toFloat).reduceByKey((a, b) => (a/ b)`